# Problem loading remote script with jQuery multiple times in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script element in my webpage, something like this:

```
<script id="myscript"></script>
```

Now, from a javascript file, I'm doing something like the following:

```
$('#myscript').src('http://foo.bar?callback=somefunc')
```

Now this remote script 'returns javascript' of the following form:

```
somefunc(somearg);
```

When I run all of this, things work neatly, the script gets loaded dynamically, and the 'somefunc' callback is executed.

The problem happens when I do the same thing again. Let's say I again call the same thing:

```
$('#myscript').src('http://foo.bar?callback=somefunc')
```

This, for some reason, DOESNT return the javascript call in Firefox only. (Works fine in IE - somefunc gets executed again as expected).

I can think of ugly workarounds (such as doing a `$('head').append('<script...'))` every time - but I'd like to know what's going on here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [`$.getScript`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript) instead of using a single script tag load scripts multiple times:

```
$.getScript("http://foo.bar?callback=somefunc");
```

That function will abstract the `script` element creation and its introduction to the DOM.

But it seems you are accessing a JSONP service, in that case you need only [`$.getJSON`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON):

```
$.getJSON("http://foo.bar?callback=?", function(json){
  // callback
});
```

Comment: getJSON probably would'nt work since the remote URL doesn't return JSON. It returns a javascript code to call the callback function.

However, I didn't try it since getScript works like a charm! Thank you so much! Adding to my yet-another-jquery-gem-that-i-didnt-know list :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I can think of ugly workarounds (such as doing a $('head').append('

Ugliness is subjective; personally, I find the technique you're trying to use (making a single script tag load multiple scripts) far uglier.

But that's not really important. Adding a new script tag *works* - so if you're having trouble with what you're doing, just use the normal method and live with it.

FWIW: Firefox probably doesn't respond because *you're not actually changing anything*... If you want to make this even uglier, append some do-nothing querystring parameter that changes each time through.

Comment: The reason I thought the latter solution is ugly is because it keeps appending script tags to the <head> of the page. Whereas, my intention is to keep only one such <script> tag.

I also tried adding a getTime() do-nothing parameter, but that doesn't work as well. Maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: You can delete them after they've loaded... But CMS's solution already does that, and it's built in to jQuery - so if that's what you're after, just go with it. :-)